# How do I use the Faceted Search on Oracle Apex with a interactive report instead of a classic report?

Tags: javascript, plsql, oracle-apex, faceted-search

**What I want to accomplish**
in Oracle APEX: I want to be able to use the **faceted search** with the ability to **hide/show** columns on the report, and then also be able to **select records** in the report so that I can manipulate them how I want to.

I can select the records with a **classic report** using JavaScript/PLSQL , or use the **interactive report**, but as far as I know you can't use a Interactive report with the faceted search. I'm fine with using the classic report, but I want to be able to hide/show columns (similarly to the action button).[Action button on Interactive Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvqV4.png)

**How can I either**:

- Use a interactive Report Instead of a classic report
- Use a Classic report with the same/similar Action button
- Or accomplish something similar?

Or where can I find a relevant resource to help me?

**I tried** changing the classic report to a interactive report, but then the faceted search says  it's Invalid [Faceted Search source section in the page designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qimQ2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faceted search is only possible out-of-the-box with Classic Reports or Cards region.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.1/htmdb/creating-a-faceted-search-manually.html#GUID-88226F4A-2971-447D-A267-1B7E37E9946D

When you use the Create Page Wizard the only option is "Diplay as" Report or Card.

But you can try a more custom approach like this:
https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/add-a-chart-to-your-faceted-search-page

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I got It to work. Similarly to this : 

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.1/htmdb/creating-a-faceted-search-manually.html#GUID-88226F4A-2971-447D-A267-1B7E37E9946D

Basically, I made the classic report hidden, and set my interactive report's "Where" Clause in PL/SQL to filter with the Faceted Search.